# How to put image in mathematica header?

Tags: image, stylesheet, display, headers-footers, wolfram-alpha-notebook-edition

I wanted to know if you can help me how to put this image in the header of the notebook

[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The documentation center has an example I believe.  Search toolbar.

Comment: Please go to Menu/Help/WolframDocumentation add the text "workflow/AddABannerToANotebook" into the search line and evaluate. You will find an explanation of how to act. If this is not what you are looking for, explain us please, what's wrong.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch [Add a Banner to a Notebook](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/AddABannerToANotebook.html).

Comment: @Edmund This is exactly where you get if you do what I described.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, now I will try to insert an image in the banner :)